# Does POST request to /v1/<account-name> in OpenStack Swift create that account?

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I'm having trouble interpreting this page:
http://docs.openstack.org/api/openstack-object-storage/1.0/content/POST_updateAccountMeta__v1__account__storage_account_services.html

It says that the POST request to account/ should update that account's metadata. It looks like it means that an account is not created, if there is a POST request to a non-existent account/. Right?

However, observing network traffic in SAIO (swift all in one), I see that the first thing that SAIO functional tests do is issue this request:

```
POST /v1/6fa5758df0d5463283c1fae5d1b32b27
```

I am pretty sure that this account does not exist. Is Swift looking to create that account with that POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the OpenStack Object Storage API v1 does not describe a method for creating an account through that service. Accounts are created through one of the following API methods, depending on the authentication service being used:

- Identity V2: [Add Tenant](http://docs.openstack.org/api/openstack-identity-service/2.0/content/POST_addTenant__v2.0_tenants_ksadm-tenants.html)
- Identity V3: [Create project](http://docs.openstack.org/api/openstack-identity-service/3/content/create-project-post-projects.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
swift@swift-1:/etc/swift$ swift stat -v
                  StorageURL: http://XXXX:8080/v1/AUTH_db8e1e2e00874ca88c9118a28bba0602
                  Auth Token: f7d527d0551c4f02a050ea7e4073ac64
                     Account: AUTH_db8e1e2e00874ca88c9118a28bba0602
                  Containers: 2
                     Objects: 17
                       Bytes: 17179869441
Objects in policy "policy-0": 17
  Bytes in policy "policy-0": 17179869441
                 X-Timestamp: 1417682993.39561
                  X-Trans-Id: txf84a1c09c7c7459a909b2-00551672fa
                Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
               Accept-Ranges: bytes



swift@swift-1:/etc/swift$ keystone tenant-list
+----------------------------------+---------+---------+
|                id                |   name  | enabled |
+----------------------------------+---------+---------+
| b1003d1e8e514e07be811316eb6f34bd |  admin  |   True  |
| db8e1e2e00874ca88c9118a28bba0602 |   demo  |   True  |
| 75497dda7a4743c3a464e3e12acc4951 |  XXX|   True  |
| 3008e419d6c147618a10d5e55eb03298 | service |   True  |
+----------------------------------+---------+---------+




As you see,the account is the tenant id of demo.
```

Answer (score 0):

surprisingly, you can create new storage account in swift without the need to create project in keystone first.
example:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://<IP>/v1/AUTH_Hello' \
--header 'X-Auth-Token: <reseller_admin_token>'
```

account AUTH_Hello is created, this way.

even with GET method, it will create AUTH_Hello.
the point is that you should use a "reseller_admin" token. i.e. token of user with the role that is like this in proxy-server.conf, keystoneauth(yoga and later) block:

```
reseller_admin_role= <role>
```

Note that there is no project related to the account AUTH_Hello in keystone databese, and therefor you can't get project-scoped token to reach this account.